# Swift: PDFDocument write

Tags: swift, quartz-graphics

Swift seems to have changed again and I'm having trouble making this code work:

```
   let pdf_url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename)
   let pdf_doc = PDFDocument.init(url: pdf_url)
   let value = "Bibbly"
   let diction = [kCGPDFContextCreator : value ] as Any

   pdf_doc!.write(toFile: filename, withOptions: (diction as [PDFDocumentWriteOption : Any]))
```

I get the following error: 'CFString' is not convertible to 'Any'.

Anyone know what the problem is? The API reference is here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436053-write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the API reference, the type of `withOptions` parameter is `[PDFDocumentWriteOption : Any]`, so declaring your `diction` as `Any` is not a good idea.

```
let diction: [PDFDocumentWriteOption : Any] = [kCGPDFContextCreator : value]
```

With this line of code, Xcode has given me a suggestion:

> 'CFString' is not implicitly convertible to 'PDFDocumentWriteOption';
>   did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

So, I have *Fix*-ed it by accepting the suggestion:

```
let pdf_url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filename)
if let pdf_doc = PDFDocument(url: pdf_url) {
    let value = "Bibbly"
    let diction: [PDFDocumentWriteOption : Any] = [kCGPDFContextCreator as PDFDocumentWriteOption : value]

    pdf_doc.write(toFile: filename, withOptions: diction)
} else {
    print("PDF document at: \(filename) cannot be opened!")
    //...
}
```

This code compiles without problems.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the necessity of having to explicitly set the type "twice" in the same definition? Or is it just because Xcode said so?

Comment: @benwiggy, if you mean finding `PDFDocumentWriteOption` twice, because the type of `kCGPDFContextCreator` is `CFString`, not `PDFDocumentWriteOption`. So, you need to explicitly convert `CFString` to `PDFDocumentWriteOption`. And the explicit type annotation `[PDFDocumentWriteOption : Any]` for `diction` is recommended to clarify that it is meant to be given to `withOptions`, for Swift compiler.

Comment: Seems a bit mad, considering `kCGPDFContextCreator` is an Apple-supplied constant, designed to be used for this. 
(And in fact on High Sierra, the script does not alter the Creator metadata field; but it does in Sierra.) But I digress. Thanks.

Comment: @benwiggy, it's quite reasonable what you feel about this situation. When Apple created this wrapper type `PDFDocumentWriteOption`, only two constant members defined for the type, `ownerPasswordOption` and `userPasswordOption`. I haven't tested if other options would work, but they should and all the valid options should be defined as constants. Better send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to Apple.